# Cannot use "import / require" into service worker file

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently building an pwa app with react. I'm facing an issue at this moment. Indeed, I'm trying to import into my sw.js which is situate in public folder some functions from my src folder... But everytime I try to run the app I've got the following message :

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token *" "Uncaught SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected token {" "..."

It's strange because it's a basic JS file...

Here's my project structure:

```
- node_modules
- public
  - assets
    - images
      (...)
  - favicon.icon
  - index.html
  - manifest.json
  - sw.js
- src
  (...)
  - indexedDB
    - database.js
    - idb.js

(...)
```

Here it's my database.js

```
import * as idb from './idb.js';


(function() {

emergencyDb = () => {
    return idb.open('emergency-store', 2, upgradeDB => {
        switch (upgradeDB.oldVersion) {
            case 0: upgradeDB.createObjectStore('emergency', { autoIncrement : true })
        }
    })
};

putEmergency = (value, key) => {
    console.log('val dans putEmergency', value);
    console.log('key dans putEmergency', key);
    return databaseLocale().emergencyDb().then(db => {
        const tx = db.transaction('emergency', 'readwrite');
        tx.objectStore('emergency').put(value, key);
        return tx.complete;
    });
};

getEmergency = (id) => {
    return databaseLocale().emergencyDb().then(db => {
        return db.transaction('emergency')
            .objectStore('emergency').get(id);
    })
};

deleteEmergency = (id) => {
    return databaseLocale().emergencyDb().then(db => {
        const tx = db.transaction('emergency', 'readwrite');
        tx.objectStore('emergency').delete(id);
        return tx.complete;
    });
};

clearEmergency = () => {
    return databaseLocale().emergencyDb().then(db => {
        const tx = db.transaction('emergency', 'readwrite');
        tx.objectStore('emergency').clear();
        return tx.complete;
    });
};

getAllEmergency = () => {
    return databaseLocale().emergencyDb().then(db => {
        return db.transaction('emergency')
            .objectStore('emergency').getAllKeys().then(keys => {
                return Promise.all(keys.map(id => databaseLocale().getEmergency(id).then(content => (Object.assign({}, { id }, content)))))
            });
    })
}


}());
```

And my idb.js

```
  (function() {

    function toArray(arr) {
      return Array.prototype.slice.call(arr);
    }

    function promisifyRequest(request) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request.onsuccess = function() {
          resolve(request.result);
        };

        request.onerror = function() {
          reject(request.error);
        };
      });
    }

    function promisifyRequestCall(obj, method, args) {
      var request;
      var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log('obj', JSON.stringify(obj));
        console.log('method', method);
        console.log('args', args);
        request = obj[method].apply(obj, args);
        promisifyRequest(request).then(resolve, reject);
      });

      p.request = request;
      return p;
    }

    function promisifyCursorRequestCall(obj, method, args) {
      var p = promisifyRequestCall(obj, method, args);
      return p.then(function(value) {
        if (!value) return;
        return new Cursor(value, p.request);
      });
    }

    function proxyProperties(ProxyClass, targetProp, properties) {
      properties.forEach(function(prop) {
        Object.defineProperty(ProxyClass.prototype, prop, {
          get: function() {
            return this[targetProp][prop];
          },
          set: function(val) {
            this[targetProp][prop] = val;
          }
        });
      });
    }

    function proxyRequestMethods(ProxyClass, targetProp, Constructor, properties) {
      properties.forEach(function(prop) {
        if (!(prop in Constructor.prototype)) return;
        ProxyClass.prototype[prop] = function() {
          console.log('this', this);
          console.log('targetProp', targetProp);
          console.log('prop', prop);
          console.log('arguments', arguments);
          return promisifyRequestCall(this[targetProp], prop, arguments);
        };
      });
    }

    function proxyMethods(ProxyClass, targetProp, Constructor, properties) {
      properties.forEach(function(prop) {
        if (!(prop in Constructor.prototype)) return;
        ProxyClass.prototype[prop] = function() {
          return this[targetProp][prop].apply(this[targetProp], arguments);
        };
      });
    }

    function proxyCursorRequestMethods(ProxyClass, targetProp, Constructor, properties) {
      properties.forEach(function(prop) {
        if (!(prop in Constructor.prototype)) return;
        ProxyClass.prototype[prop] = function() {
          return promisifyCursorRequestCall(this[targetProp], prop, arguments);
        };
      });
    }

    function Index(index) {
      this._index = index;
    }

    proxyProperties(Index, '_index', [
      'name',
      'keyPath',
      'multiEntry',
      'unique'
    ]);

    proxyRequestMethods(Index, '_index', IDBIndex, [
      'get',
      'getKey',
      'getAll',
      'getAllKeys',
      'count'
    ]);

    proxyCursorRequestMethods(Index, '_index', IDBIndex, [
      'openCursor',
      'openKeyCursor'
    ]);

    function Cursor(cursor, request) {
      this._cursor = cursor;
      this._request = request;
    }

    proxyProperties(Cursor, '_cursor', [
      'direction',
      'key',
      'primaryKey',
      'value'
    ]);

    proxyRequestMethods(Cursor, '_cursor', IDBCursor, [
      'update',
      'delete'
    ]);

    // proxy 'next' methods
    ['advance', 'continue', 'continuePrimaryKey'].forEach(function(methodName) {
      if (!(methodName in IDBCursor.prototype)) return;
      Cursor.prototype[methodName] = function() {
        var cursor = this;
        var args = arguments;
        return Promise.resolve().then(function() {
          cursor._cursor[methodName].apply(cursor._cursor, args);
          return promisifyRequest(cursor._request).then(function(value) {
            if (!value) return;
            return new Cursor(value, cursor._request);
          });
        });
      };
    });

    function ObjectStore(store) {
      this._store = store;
    }

    ObjectStore.prototype.createIndex = function() {
      return new Index(this._store.createIndex.apply(this._store, arguments));
    };

    ObjectStore.prototype.index = function() {
      return new Index(this._store.index.apply(this._store, arguments));
    };

    proxyProperties(ObjectStore, '_store', [
      'name',
      'keyPath',
      'indexNames',
      'autoIncrement'
    ]);

    proxyRequestMethods(ObjectStore, '_store', IDBObjectStore, [
      'put',
      'add',
      'delete',
      'clear',
      'get',
      'getAll',
      'getKey',
      'getAllKeys',
      'count'
    ]);

    proxyCursorRequestMethods(ObjectStore, '_store', IDBObjectStore, [
      'openCursor',
      'openKeyCursor'
    ]);

    proxyMethods(ObjectStore, '_store', IDBObjectStore, [
      'deleteIndex'
    ]);

    function Transaction(idbTransaction) {
      this._tx = idbTransaction;
      this.complete = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        idbTransaction.oncomplete = function() {
          resolve();
        };
        idbTransaction.onerror = function() {
          reject(idbTransaction.error);
        };
        idbTransaction.onabort = function() {
          reject(idbTransaction.error);
        };
      });
    }

    Transaction.prototype.objectStore = function() {
      return new ObjectStore(this._tx.objectStore.apply(this._tx, arguments));
    };

    proxyProperties(Transaction, '_tx', [
      'objectStoreNames',
      'mode'
    ]);

    proxyMethods(Transaction, '_tx', IDBTransaction, [
      'abort'
    ]);

    function UpgradeDB(db, oldVersion, transaction) {
      this._db = db;
      this.oldVersion = oldVersion;
      this.transaction = new Transaction(transaction);
    }

    UpgradeDB.prototype.createObjectStore = function() {
      return new ObjectStore(this._db.createObjectStore.apply(this._db, arguments));
    };

    proxyProperties(UpgradeDB, '_db', [
      'name',
      'version',
      'objectStoreNames'
    ]);

    proxyMethods(UpgradeDB, '_db', IDBDatabase, [
      'deleteObjectStore',
      'close'
    ]);

    function DB(db) {
      this._db = db;
    }

    DB.prototype.transaction = function() {
      return new Transaction(this._db.transaction.apply(this._db, arguments));
    };

    proxyProperties(DB, '_db', [
      'name',
      'version',
      'objectStoreNames'
    ]);

    proxyMethods(DB, '_db', IDBDatabase, [
      'close'
    ]);

    // Add cursor iterators
    // TODO: remove this once browsers do the right thing with promises
    ['openCursor', 'openKeyCursor'].forEach(function(funcName) {
      [ObjectStore, Index].forEach(function(Constructor) {
        Constructor.prototype[funcName.replace('open', 'iterate')] = function() {
          var args = toArray(arguments);
          var callback = args[args.length - 1];
          var nativeObject = this._store || this._index;
          var request = nativeObject[funcName].apply(nativeObject, args.slice(0, -1));
          request.onsuccess = function() {
            callback(request.result);
          };
        };
      });
    });

    // polyfill getAll
    [Index, ObjectStore].forEach(function(Constructor) {
      if (Constructor.prototype.getAll) return;
      Constructor.prototype.getAll = function(query, count) {
        var instance = this;
        var items = [];

        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
          instance.iterateCursor(query, function(cursor) {
            if (!cursor) {
              resolve(items);
              return;
            }
            items.push(cursor.value);

            // Modification ici 
            // if (count !== undefined && items.length == count) {
            if (count !== undefined && items.length === count) {
              resolve(items);
              return;
            }
            cursor.continue();
          });
        });
      };
    });

    var exp = {
      open: function(name, version, upgradeCallback) {
        var p = promisifyRequestCall(indexedDB, 'open', [name, version]);
        var request = p.request;

        request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
          if (upgradeCallback) {
            upgradeCallback(new UpgradeDB(request.result, event.oldVersion, request.transaction));
          }
        };

        return p.then(function(db) {
          return new DB(db);
        });
      },
      delete: function(name) {
        return promisifyRequestCall(indexedDB, 'deleteDatabase', [name]);
      }
    };

    if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
      module.exports = exp;
      module.exports.default = module.exports;
    }
    else {
      this.idb = exp;
    }
  }());
```

And finally my sw.js

```
// import * as idb from './assets/indexedDB/idb.js'; < -- BUG HERE CANNOT IMPORT THE FILE


const BASE_URL_BACKEND = 'http://localhost:8080';

const cacheName ='emmergency-1.0';

self.addEventListener('install', evt => {
    console.log(`SW installé à ${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}`);

    let cachePromise = caches.open(cacheName).then(cache =>{
        return cache.addAll([
            '/'
        ])
        .then(console.log("Cache initialisé"))
        .catch(console.err);
    });

    evt.waitUntil(cachePromise);
});


// Supprimer les anciennes versions du cache
self.addEventListener('activate', evt => {
    console.log('Activate evt', evt);
    let cacheCleanedPromise = caches.keys().then(keys => {
        keys.forEach(key => {
            if(key != cacheName){
                return caches.delete(key);
            }
        })
    });
    evt.waitUntil(cacheCleanedPromise)
});



self.addEventListener('fetch', evt => {
    // if(!navigator.onLine){
    //     const headers = { headers : {'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8'}};
    //     evt.respondWith(new Response('<h1>Pas de connexion internet</h1>', headers));
    // }


    // // Stratégie de cache only with network fallback
    // evt.respondWith(
    //     caches.match(evt.request).then(res => {
    //         if(res){
    //             console.log(`Url fetchée depuis le cache ${evt.request.url}`, res);
    //             return res;
    //         }
    //         return fetch(evt.request).then(newResponse => {
    //             console.log(`Url récrupérée sur le réseau puis mise en cache ${evt.request.url}`, newResponse);

    //             caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => cache.put(evt.request, newResponse))
    //             return newResponse.clone();
    //         })
    //     })
    // );

    // Stratégie de network first with cache fallback
    // evt.respondWith(
    //     fetch(evt.request).then(res => {
    //         console.log(`${evt.request.url} fetchée depuis le réseau`);
    //         caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => cache.put(evt.request, res));
    //         return res.clone();
    //     }).catch(err => {
    //         console.log(`${evt.request.url} fetchée depuis le cache`);
    //         return caches.match(evt.request);
    //     })
    // );

});


// // Notification persistante - Peut être affiché même quand l'utilisateur n'est pas sur l'application
// self.registration.showNotification("Notification depuis le SW", {
//     body : 'Je suis un notification "persistante"',
//     actions : [
//         {action : 'accept', title: 'Accepter'},
//         {action : 'refuse', title: 'Refuser'}
//     ]
// })

// self.addEventListener('notificationclose', evt => {
//     console.log('Notification fermée', evt); 
// })

// self.addEventListener('notificationclick', evt => {
//     if(evt.action === 'accept'){
//         console.log('Notification acceptée');
//     }
//     else if(evt.action === 'refuse'){
//         console.log('Notification refusée');
//     }
//     else{
//         console.log('Vous avez cliqué sur la notification (Pas sur les boutons)');
//     }

//     evt.notification.close();
// })


self.addEventListener('push', evt => {
    console.log('Push event', evt);
    console.log('Data envoyée par la push notification des dev tools : ', evt.data.text());
    const title = evt.data.text();

    evt.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification(title, 
            { 
                body: 'Ca fonctionne', 
                image: 'images/icons/icon-152x152.png'
            }
        ));
})

self.addEventListener('sync', event => {
    if(event.tag === 'sync-emergencies'){
        console.log('Attemting to sync', event.tag);

        event.waitUntil(
            getAllEmergency().then(emergencies => {
                const unsynced = emergencies.filter(emergency => emergency.unsynced);

                console.log("UNSYNCED =", unsynced);

                return Promise.all(unsynced.map(emergency => {
                    fetch(`${BASE_URL_BACKEND}/api/calls`, {
                        headers : {
                            'Accept': 'application/json',
                            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                        },
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: JSON.stringify(emergency)
                    })
                    .then(() => {
                        return putEmergency(Object.assign({}, emergency, { unsynced: false}), emergency.id);
                    });
                }))
            })
        )
    }
});
```

I absolutely needs some function from "database.js" into my "sw.js" file... But I can't import it... Any help please ?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

there is no return from `IIFE`.You need to add it.

**idb.js**

```
(function() {
      //......

        return {
            exp
        }

  }());
```

Comment: In which file ? I'm not sure that modification will solve the problem... I'm not able to import external js file into sw.js ...

Comment: I'm even not able to import module from node_module with "import axios from 'axios';" in my sw.js...

Comment: This doesnt serve the purpose. U cannot import it inisde service worker